# Why can't I call "gist" on "while"? (Perl 6)

Tags: raku

I can call the `gist` method on the `say` built-in function:

```
&say.gist
```

> ```
> sub say (| is raw) { #`(Sub|54790064) ... }
> ```

Why can't I call `gist` on `while`?

```
&while.gist
```

> ```
> ===SORRY!=== Error while compiling <unknown file>
> Undeclared routine:
>     while used at line 1
> ```

Obviously `while` isn't a "routine" but `say` is. But I thought that all of the built-ins in Perl 6 were really functions that we could redefine.

Comment: `while` is more like a macro than a routine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I thought that all of the built-ins in Perl 6 were really functions that we could redefine.

`while` is not a routine or macro, but part of the syntax, defined in [Perl6's grammar](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/ce69f3089c67197f51ca2880da542e2f044d46ca/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L1379).

If you wanted to redefine it, you would have to create your own slang, which currently involves black magic.

For some reason I have yet to figure out, it only works when done in a module (otherwise, `%*LANG` seems not to be defined).

Let's call the module `froop.pm6`:

```
use nqp;

sub EXPORT {
    nqp::bindkey(%*LANG, 'MAIN', nqp::atkey(%*LANG, 'MAIN').^mixin(role {
        rule statement_control:sym<while> {
            [$<sym>=froop{
                $/.hash<sym>.^mixin: role {
                    method Str { 'while' }
                }
            }|$<sym>=until]<.kok> {}
            <xblock>
        }
    }));

    once Map.new
}
```

This replaces the `while` keyword (in statement position) with `froop`, eg

```
use froop;
my $i = 0;
froop $i < 5 { say $i++ }
```

Comment: Perl 6 gets amazinger and amazinger. Also, hey, look, Perl 6 is LISP, what else is new? :)